# Nginx Configured and Running, but Requests Not Redirected to Domain Name

Tags: java, linux, nginx, web-hosting, vps

I have successfully configured and started Nginx on my server. The Nginx service is running and listening on the correct port. I've set up a configuration block to redirect requests from my domain name to my application running on a different port, but for some reason, the requests are not being redirected as expected.
Here's a simplified version of my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name traceps.shop www.traceps.shop
    proxy_pass http://62.xx.xx.xx:8080;
}
```

I've double-checked that my domain name ([www.traceps.shop](http://www.traceps.shop)) is correctly pointed to my server's IP address. When I try to access my application through the domain name, the page doesn't load as expected. However, when I use the IP address directly with the port, the application works fine.

Could there be something in my Nginx configuration that's preventing the redirection to work as intended? What steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Comment: Why the Java tag in an ngnix question? This is an infrastructure question probably not suitable for Stackoverlow.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be missing a semicolon (;)?

```
    server_name traceps.shop www.traceps.shop;
```

Comment: but still not workng